# After unplugging my PC from the outlet, sometimes it won't boot for a long time

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power

Before I go to sleep, I unplug my PC from the outlet, due to concerns about power spikes or something of the sort frying my computer. However, sometimes, when I wake up and plug it back into the outlet, it doesn't get any power when I press the button. Most times, I can just wait 10 minutes and try again, but occasionally it takes a really long time, and when I can finally boot, the system's clock is wrong by several hours. Today, I pressed the power button, and it powered up all fans and RGB lighting (but not the CPU fan, beeps, or any video output) by itself about 10 minutes later, and after 15 more minutes, the CPU finally turned on and I got access to my operating system. I've already swapped my CMOS battery since then, as I grew suspicious of the wrong clock, but to no avail.

What could be wrong, and how can I figure out which part is causing this issue?

Comment: Given your description, it appears the power button circuitry may have a hardware fault. Get the machine serviced.

Comment: An hardware fault no doubt but unlikely the one suggested above. How old is the machine? It feels like failing capacitors in the PSU and/or motherboard. In the meantime keep it plugged in, your worries are unfounded.

Comment: so the battery change fixed the clock problem? Some systems "cold-boot double-post" when the power is pulled from the wall, but rarely would it take as long as you describe unless your BIOS has a memory check setting or has whatever your mainboard calls faster boot disabled. see for example ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_boot )

Comment: How do you shut down prior to unplugging? If the system is actually in a *sleep* state, pulling the plug is *bad*. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states